# Is asking about a movie on topic?

Tags: support, scope

I have read about a movie on Wikipedia but googling and looking at IMDB no result at all (it is based on a book and I find a lot of results about the book). Would it be on topic to ask if anyone knows anything about this movie? Alternative titles [that would make it easier to google]? Where it could be bought/streamed?

Answer (score 1):

## No

None of those questions are appropriate for Movies & TV.

> **Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:**
>
> - Identifying a movie or TV series
> - Locating or purchasing movie or TV content.
> - A title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series.

Comment: My questions has very little to do with any of your examples. I want to read more about the movie mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alessandro_Perissinotto in point 1 in the Anna Pavesi's trilogy a bit down. E.g., reviews, which company that produced it?

Comment: Your question seemed to indicate that you did not know the details of the movie. Regardless, the information you seem to want would not be appropriate for M&TV.

Comment: No, I only know that it exists and that there are photos of a house I in it that I am interested in seeing.

Comment: Thus you are asking us to identify for you and we don't do that.

Comment: @d-b There is no mention of a movie there. That is a trilogy of *books*.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The movie is mentioned in this article, under its French name https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/auvergne-rhone-alpes/projet-ambitieux-rehabilitation-au-pavillon-keller-livet-gavet-866379.html

Comment: @Paulie_D No, you are wrong.

Comment: @d-b Not me....

Comment: ...but I think you are looking for [Maison Keller](https://www.google.com/search?q=maison+keller&oq=Maison+Keller&aqs=chrome.0.0l8.9963j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @d-b And if you search using that french name you get plenty of results, you'll even get the English title etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Everything I found referred to the book, not the movie.